# apportable uikit / coredata compatibility

Tags: android, ios, cocoa, apportable

Concerning `UIKit` and `CoreData`, what level of compatibility has Apportable achieved?

While there are substantial examples given on the site, they appear to be exclusively games, dependent on pre existing cross platform stuff like *Cocos2d* and `CFLite`.

My projects are reliant on `CoreData`, `FRC`, `UIKit` not to mention the usual 3rd party libraries like `AFHTTP`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download their free [SDK](http://www.apportable.com/) and then have a look in `~/.apportable/SDK/System/` to see what sorts of things are supported.  CoreData is in there, so there is some level of support.

Of course, just because the method is in the header doesn't mean it is 100% supported, but they are very responsive in the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/apportable-discuss) to inquiries as to level of support and timeframe for supporting it.  They update their SDK approximately weekly, it seems, so support gets better all the time.

My recommendation is just try building with their SDK and see how it goes.

My experience with their UIKit support has been that it generally exceeded my expectations.  Most of the issues have been in the UITableView support.

And by AFHTTP, do you mean AFNetworking?  Apportable has no issues with AFNetworking.  My projects they have ported use it and it has worked just fine.  I'm not sure what FRC is.